# Understanding table locking in MS SQL TSQL Transactions

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, locking

I wanted to make the old following query safe from data races when running them in parallel. The query checks if a row exists in in a table using specific criteria and if such row does not exist, it inserts new one with new data. Old query is pasted below:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @txtPer VARCHAR(MAX) = @nro;
    DECLARE @txtCmin VARCHAR(MAX) = @min;
    DECLARE @txtCmax VARCHAR(MAX) = @max;
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SEND WHERE MSG LIKE (@txtPer + '%') AND STATE < 2 AND ID = 1)
    BEGIN
        ----Time of check is not time of use
        ----Someone could possibly do another insert before this == data race
        INSERT INTO SEND (SNDID, ID, MSGCODE, MSG, STATE, INFO, INFO_TEXT, CHANGEDATE, CREATEDATE)
        SELECT MAX(SNDID)+10,1,1,(@txtPer + @txtCmin + '           ' + @txtCmax),0,0,' ',getdate(),getdate() FROM SEND
    END
END
```

I came up with a new version which is slightly cleaner and uses exclusive table lock:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
DECLARE @txtPer VARCHAR(MAX) = @nro;
DECLARE @txtCmin VARCHAR(MAX) = @min;
DECLARE @txtCmax VARCHAR(MAX) = @max;

DECLARE @IdMax INT
--Get MAX and simultaneously acquire lock for the table to prevent modifications during this transaction?
SELECT @IdMax=MAX(SNDID) FROM SEND WITH(TABLOCKX)

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM SEND WHERE MSG LIKE (@txtPer + '%') AND STATE < 2 AND ID = 1)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO SEND (SNDID, ID, MSGCODE, MSG, STATE, INFO, INFO_TEXT, CHANGEDATE, CREATEDATE)
    VALUES((@IdMax + 10),1,1,(@txtPer + @txtCmin + '           ' + @txtCmax),0,0,' ',getdate(),getdate())
END
COMMIT; --writes potential change and releases table lock?
```

Is my understanding correct that the table lock acquired during `SELECT MAX()` operation (and possibly others in the same transaction) holds until the entire transaction is finished with the `COMMIT` statement? DB is an old MS SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is my understanding correct that the table lock acquired during SELECT MAX() operation (and possibly others in the same transaction) holds until the entire transaction is finished with the COMMIT statement?

Yes, as long as it's `TABLOCKX` and not `TABLOCK`. This only works if you use pessmistic locking, not optimistic snapshot locking, as mentioned by @DavidBrowne.

However, this is extremely inefficient.

- It will completely lock the whole table from reading or writing. Instead use `UPDLOCK` and `SERIALIZABLE` (or `HOLDLOCK`) hints.

  - The `SERIALIZABLE` hint is necessary to lock even the non-existence of the data (ie a range lock) ensuring that no-one else can insert.
  - The `UPDLOCK` hint is necessary in order to place U-locks on the table, which prevents anyone else requesting a U-lock from proceeding, while still alowing read-only queries. This tend to prevent deadlocks at the serializable isolation level.
- Ensure your table is indexed on the `ID, MSG, STATE` columns, or the `ID, STATE, MSG`, in order for the `NOT EXISTS` to be efficient.
- It also searches the entire table for the max `SNDID` value, you should be using an `IDENTITY` column instead.
- Use `XACT_ABORT ON` to ensure rollback happens properly in case of errors.

```sql
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRAN;

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM SEND WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
    WHERE MSG LIKE CONCAT(@nro, '%')
      AND STATE < 2
      AND ID = 1
)
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO SEND (ID, MSGCODE, MSG, STATE, INFO, INFO_TEXT, CHANGEDATE, CREATEDATE)
        VALUES (1, 1, CONCAT(@nro, @min, '           ', @max), 0, 0, ' ', getdate(), getdate());
END;

COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is my understanding correct that the table lock acquired during SELECT MAX() operation (and possibly others in the same transaction) holds until the entire transaction is finished with the COMMIT statement?

Yes.  But that lock will not block another session from reading the table if the database is configured with READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT.

The correct way to serialize these is with a lock hint on the select that decides whether the row exists, like this:

`SELECT 1 FROM SEND WITH(UPDLOCK,HOLDLOCK)...`